# How to show datapicker in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I use `bootstrap ui library` in Angular JS. Here there is Datepicket element.
How I can show datepicker in two inputs?
[Link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to library

I tried:

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}">
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}">
```

But this way opens inputs together

Comment: what are you using to actually _open_ the datepicker? Is there a button and the `ng-click` sets a variable like the example in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ritesh's answer might correct it, the explanation isn't clear.

The reason you are having both open at the same time is because of this: `is-open="opened"`.

The `is-open` is used to open the specified datepicker when this scope value is true. You mapped *both* datepickers to the same value. So when you call `open($event)` and set `$scope.opened = true`, it opens both.

What you really want to do is have a different function you call that sets the correct variable. So change the HTML to:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="open($event)" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtModel" is-open="opened" />
<input type="text" ng-click="open2($event)" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtModel2" is-open="opened2" />
```

And then add the function to your controller:

```
$scope.open2 = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened2 = true;
  };
```

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BMFtRJeEhN44aHMS2x84?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide minimum required attributes and without using `ng-model` how do you retrieve the date from the datepicker.

try using like this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtModel" is-open="opened" />
```

add this script in your controller :

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();

$scope.opened = true;
```

};

[working plunker for date picker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uXjl0mmml0dWYhcMxYMd?p=preview)

Comment: @Hamed have a look at the working plunker [http://plnkr.co/edit/uXjl0mmml0dWYhcMxYMd?p=preview]

Comment: Look please, it opens two input together http://plnkr.co/edit/lvXJVhhp9Utg2DhInuVF?p=preview

Comment: Also how I can add own class to pop-up calendar?

Comment: you can not add a class to the pop up using datepickerconfig or something else. You better keep the datepicker within a container with a class name and  write styles.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your plunker,it was opening two datepickers at once because **$event** was passed as **opened** for both input texts.

Change your input text to this

```
<input type="text" ng-click="open($event)" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtModel" is-open="opened" />
 <input type="text" ng-click="open($event)" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtModel2" is-open="opened2" />
```

Here is the working plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/pCjeXpey3BYgKGBCffAp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, never worked on ionic framework, but i guess it should work. Since, the bootstrap library is going to be same.